# Convergence in $L^2$.

Tags: measure-theory

I give up with this. Let $f$, $g$, $f_m \in L^2$, $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that if $f_m$ converge to $f$ in $L^2$ then

$\int f_m g d\lambda$ converges to $\int fg d\lambda$

Comment: Hint: Holder inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$| \int (f-f_n)g| \le \|g\| \|f-f_n\|$.